# Magento Update Customer Telephone

Tags: magento-1.9

I am taking customer telephone on success page and i want to update customer Telephone in magento this is my code

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId());
if($order->getCustomerId() === NULL){
echo $order->getBillingAddress()->getTelephone();
```

Comment: where do you want to update the customer telephone?

Comment: i am working in succes page

Comment: first customer enter his number on checkout page and on success page i send her number to sms api but i checked if customer number not valid then i give customer text box write his number on it and then send it to api again and same i want to update my database

Answer (score 0):

for getting data change
from -

> $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
>           ->load($customerId)->getData(); // insert customer ID
>       //Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($id)->getData();

```
foreach ($customer->getPrimaryBillingAddress() as $address)
{
    $data = $address->toArray();
    var_dump($data);
}
```

to

> $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
>           ->load($customerId); // insert customer ID
>       //Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($id)->getData();

```
print_r( $customer->getPrimaryBillingAddress()->getData());
```

If you want to update primary billing address telephone from mobile number(custom attribute) IF telephone field is empty

then using customer address model

> (Mage::getModel('customer/address'))

update this address telephone.

```
$address=Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($customer->getPrimaryBillingAddress()->getEntityId());
$address->setTelephone($customer->getMobile());
$address->save();
```

Comment: is this for register customer?

Comment: yes, its for register customer

Comment: but i want for guest

Comment: you can get custid of guest users also, atlst try for the code then raise queries.

Comment: how? can get can i get form order id?